# Comparing two strings gives false as an output

Tags: java, string

I want to know why the result of this program gives false when both of the strings are exactly the same, also why is the text "WHY" not appearing in the console.

```
public class prac {
    public static void main (String args []){
String a = "wtf";
String b = "wtf";
System.out.println("WHY" + a==b);

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: use a.equals(b) always for string comparison

Comment: `==` is not going to work for Strings or other non-primitive objects. Use `.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"WHY" + a` does not equal `b`.

You also need to compare strings by value using `.equals()`.